# Boolean Expression - Order of Operations

Tags: vba, excel, boolean, operator-precedence

I have a test in Excel VBA:

```
If (test1) And (test2) And (test3) Then
    'do something
End If
```

In C, Java, etc. test1 would be run first, then test2, then test3. Critically, if test1 is false the whole test is false so the remaining tests do not run.

Does that happen in this case with VBA? If so, in which order are the tests running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In all VBs prior to .NET there is no such thing as short-circuit. All expressions will be evaluated even if not required. If you want short-curcuit, do nested IFs.