# Object Variable or With Block variable not set using Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two subs called `FindTempRow` and `FindBatchRow`

```
Sub FindTempRow()  
    With Worksheets("TEMPLATES").Range("G:G")

        Set t = .Find("Template", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not t Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress1 = t.Address
            Do
                Call FindBatchRow
                Set t = .FindNext(t)
            Loop While Not t Is Nothing And t.Address <> FirstAddress1
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Sub FindBatchRow()
        With Worksheets("DISTRIBUTION LIST").Range("C:C")
            Set d = .Find(BatchNo, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not d Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress2 = d.Address
                    Do
                        Set d = .FindNext(d)
                    Loop While Not d Is Nothing And d.Address <> FirstAddress2
                End If
        End With
End Sub
```

**FindTempRow** is calling **FindBatchRow** inside a **Do While Loop**.

The problem is whenever I run the code it gives me an error: `Runtime Error Code (91) Object Variable or With Block variable not set`

The code that gives an error is located in **FindTempRow**:

```
Loop While Not t Is Nothing And t.Address <> FirstAddress1
```

I tried removing `call FindBatchRow` in `Sub FindTempRow` and it runs fine. It seems my code is forgetting the **address** value of **t** whenever another **find method** is called in `sub FindBatchRow`

**SOLUTION:** by @Rory

**REPLACE:** `Set t = .FindNext(t)` from **Sub FindBatchRow**

**WITH:** `Set t = .Find("Template", After:=t, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: Please step throught the code with F8. At which line does the error occur then?

Comment: `Loop While Not t Is Nothing And t.Address <> FirstAddress1`

Comment: Sorry I forgot, the code above is the one that gives error

Comment: @ChadPatrick are these 2 `Sub`s code in the same module ? where and how is `t` defined ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Boolean Expression - Order of Operations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/345399/11683) and [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/11683).

Comment: the 2 subs are inside the same form not module, and t is defined inside the code which is `set t  = .Find("Template", LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: `FindNext` repeats the **last** search. Since you changed the search parameters in your `FindBatchRow` routine, you are actually repeating that search,not the original one. You need to use `Find` again and specify the same parameters.

Comment: @Rory can you give me a sample on how to do that?

Comment: Instead of `FindNext` repeat the `Find`: `Set t = .Find("Template", After:=t, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Answer (score 2):

In the first run of the loop, if nothing is found then, when your code attempts to get address from `t`  which is actually nothing, it throws error. Remove this part from your loop`And t.Address <> FirstAddress1` . Instead check this condition inside the do loop with a If statement and when true jump out of the loop using`ExitDo`

Answer (score 0):

VBA always resolves all parts of in the if clause (or here in the while clause) so if in an you use the and operator and the first one is false, the second one gets checked nevertheless, which fails if t is nothing. Do something like this:

```
Do
    Call FindBatchRow
    Set t = .FindNext(t)
    Dim a As boolean
    a = False
    If Not t is Nothing
        If t.Address <> FirstAddress1
            a = True
        End If
    End If
Loop While a
```

The same should be done in your FindBatchRow accordingly.