# Using VB code to create timestamps as data is entered, works fine but still returning error

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to capture the time of data entry (in column 1) for each value input to (column 5). I'm using this modified bit of code I got from here:
[Excel Formula which places date/time in cell when data is entered in another cell in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170379/excel-formula-which-places-date-time-in-cell-when-data-is-entered-in-another-cel)

This code functions as intended but still returns "Runtime Error '1004': Application Defined or Object Defined Error". Is there any way I can ignore this error, or perhaps fix the problem? I'm fairly new at this so bear with me.

- My Target Column (5) Is where I'm checking for a number greater than 0, this is the trigger to update the time in Column 1
- Column 5 has text cells above the range (E9:E50) I want to check. Which may be causing issue
- When I go to debug, the second line of my code is highlighted with no other hints

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Offset(0, -4).Value = "" Then
        If Target.Column > 0 Then
            Target.Offset(0, -4) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Even when the Column is not 5, the test of offset -4 column is performed, which may sometimes be less than 1.

Comment: The second part of the `And` is [going to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/345399/11683) even when the first part is false. You need to move the `Target.Offset(0, -4).Value = ""` condition into a nested `If`. Otherwise you will be getting errors when the column number is less than 5. You do not need the `Target.Column > 0` condition, it is always true. Move the `Target.Offset(0, -4).Value = ""` in its place.

Comment: So fast, thank you! This was just what I needed.

Comment: I see your edits,  I had the check for "Target.Column > 0", but that was not the right code for what I wanted, I should have had "Target.Value > 0", because I have the values default to 0 in those cells. Thanks again for the detailed response.